# Is there any function I can use to delete the cell automatically but at the same time keep the evaluated results

Tags: front-end, notebooks, input

For, example, in the following code

```
a = DensityPlot[{Sin[x] Cos[y], Sin[x + y] Cos[x - y]}, {x, -5, 
5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotLayout -> "Row"];
a // Rasterize // CellPrint[TextCell[#, "Text"]] &
```

[image]

I want to delete this input cell, and only keep the result in the notebook.

Cause I don't need the code!

I want it done by putting some function in the input cell!

So I wonder is there this kind of function that can achieve this functionality!

Comment: `NotebookDelete@EvaluationCell[]`?

Comment: That is really useful, thanks, bro